# WCF client disable encryption

Tags: java, c#, web-services, wcf, encryption

I have a Java service that I need to consume and the security requirements state the message needs to be signed and timestamped, but encryption is not required.

I have tried adopting a custom binding and have successfully added the signing an time stamp but the message body is always being encrypted, as per example:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <s:Header>
        <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo2ZxfrkBGk9AsTA8KWukb2AAAAAADLwbydLv0kmqZo1361cxb7JSYAqPOP5HmzAGAtf6H7MACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData>
        <o:Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:o="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <u:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-f761d810-63b1-485b-a89f-1d3da446f273-1">
                <u:Created>2016-05-11T14:34:10.237Z</u:Created>
                <u:Expires>2016-05-11T14:39:10.237Z</u:Expires>
            </u:Timestamp>
            <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-76114032-1c65-4a4d-9f54-9d5d68e0dc2b-2">...</o:BinarySecurityToken>
            <e:EncryptedKey Id="_0" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-oaep-mgf1p">
                    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
                </e:EncryptionMethod>
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:KeyIdentifier ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509SubjectKeyIdentifier" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">WLVP0ah+F2LGQm9mvqQfPJ/sA4w=</o:KeyIdentifier>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
                <e:CipherData>...</e:CipherData>
                <e:ReferenceList>
                    <e:DataReference URI="#_2"/>
                </e:ReferenceList>
            </e:EncryptedKey>
            <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                <SignedInfo>
                    <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
                    <Reference URI="#_1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>2PRP+JjT6OhZcHo9QUMtvwNltY4=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                    <Reference URI="#uuid-f761d810-63b1-485b-a89f-1d3da446f273-1">
                        <Transforms>
                            <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
                        </Transforms>
                        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
                        <DigestValue>zkmVC2HFZxdBV03114Ije8gAQE0=</DigestValue>
                    </Reference>
                </SignedInfo>
                <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
                <KeyInfo>
                    <o:SecurityTokenReference>
                        <o:Reference ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" URI="#uuid-76114032-1c65-4a4d-9f54-9d5d68e0dc2b-2"/>
                    </o:SecurityTokenReference>
                </KeyInfo>
            </Signature>
        </o:Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body u:Id="_1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <e:EncryptedData Id="_2" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:e="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
            <e:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc"/>
            <e:CipherData>
                <e:CipherValue>...</e:CipherValue>
            </e:CipherData>
        </e:EncryptedData>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

This is my config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="SignTimestampOnly">
                <security messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11"
                    authenticationMode="MutualCertificate" requireDerivedKeys="false" includeTimestamp="true" keyEntropyMode="ClientEntropy" securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampFirst"
                    requireSignatureConfirmation="false" messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt" enableUnsecuredResponse="true" requireSecurityContextCancellation="false"
                    allowInsecureTransport="true" />
                <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8"/>
                <httpTransport />
            </binding>

        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost/myurl" binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="SignTimestampOnly" contract="IService" name="Service">
            <identity>
                <dns value="Service" />
            </identity>
        </endpoint>
    </client>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <clientCredentials>
                    <clientCertificate findValue="..." storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                                       storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
                    <serviceCertificate>
                        <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
                        <defaultCertificate findValue="..." storeLocation="CurrentUser"
                                        storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" />
                    </serviceCertificate>
                </clientCredentials>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I turn encryption off but keep signing and timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This page explains how to disable encryption.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/72c5a1b1-55d6-49b0-8a4b-7db763d90ad3/disable-encryption-of-body-signed-with-x509-certificate?forum=wcf

You can set this behavior at your ServiceContract interface attribute.

```
// Set the ProtectionLevel on the whole service to Sign.
[ServiceContract(ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign)]
public interface Calculator
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa347791.aspx

Comment: I have no control over the service, I am consuming it.

Comment: Please take a look at the first link I gave you. I think the last comment of that topic is what you need. You can change the client proxy's endpoint contract's protection behavior.

Comment: Setting `proxy.Endpoint.Contract.ProtectionLevel = ProtectionLevel.Sign;` got things working for me. Thanks.